# JavaScript Form Validation Not Working onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm working through a section of a book on form validation with JavaScript.  Unfortunately, the example in the book isn't working.  I understand and follow the logic behind the validation (The general idea is that if any of the individual field validation functions return a value to the validate function then an alert will display and the form will not be submitted `onSubmit`) , but nothing is happening onSubmit.  I have looked over the script and html a few times and can't find anything wrong (I even went to the book site and copied the code from there).

Here is the html form and the JavaScript validation:

```
    <script>
    function validate(form) 
    {
            fail  = validateForename(form.forename.value)
            fail += validateSurname(form.surname.value)
            fail += validateUsername(form.username.value)
            fail += validatePassword(form.password.value)
            fail += validateAge(form.age.value)
            fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)
            if (fail == "") return true
            else {alert(fail); return false }
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function validateForename(field) {
            if (field == "") return "No Forename was entered.\n"
            return ""
    }

    function validateSurname(field) {
            if (field == "") return "No Surname was entered.\n"
            return ""
    }

    function validateUsername(field) {
            if (field == "") return "No Username was entered.\n"
            else if (field.length < 5) return "Usernames must be at least 5 characters.\n"
            else if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(field)) return "Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _ allowed in Usernames.\n"
            return ""
    }

    function validatePassword(field) {
            if (field == "") return "No Password was entered.\n"
            else if (field.length < 6) return "Passwords must be at least 6 characters.\n"
            else if (! /[a-z]/.test(field) || ! /[A-Z]/.test(field) || ! /[0-9]/.test(field)) return "Passwords require one each of a-z, A-Z and 0-9.\n"
            return ""
    }

    function validateAge(field) {
            if (isNAN(field)) return "No Age was entered.\n"
            else if (field < 18 || field > 110) return "Age must be between 18 and 110.\n"
            return ""
    }

    function validateEmail(field) {
            if (field == "") return "No Email was entered.\n"
                    else if (!((field.indexOf(".") > 0) && (field.indexOf("@") > 0)) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field)) return "The Email address is invalid.\n"
            return ""
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <table class="signup" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Signup Form</th>
    <form method="post" action="adduser.php" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
    <tr><td>Forename</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="forename" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Surname</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="surname" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="16" name="username" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="12" name="password" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Age</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="age" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" maxlength="64" name="email" /></td>
    </tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Signup" /></td>
    </tr></form></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

> nothing is happening onSubmit

Assuming that you really do mean that **nothing** is happening, and that that includes "the form being submitted" then the problem is one that could be resolved by making the HTML [valid](http://validator.w3.org/).

A form cannot be wrapped around table rows *and* be inside the table those rows belong to. Some browsers recover from this error my moving the form to after the table (but leaving the inputs inside the table). This means that the inputs are not inside the form and sit around doing nothing.

As a quick fix, move the form so it surrounds the table.

As a proper solution, stop using tables for layout. CSS is a good tool for [form layout](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+form#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=css+forms&pbx=1&oq=css+forms&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1716l1716l0l1951l1l1l0l0l0l0l155l155l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=d92b7c52a83564cd&biw=1193&bih=683).

You should also take advantage of [the label element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), and not fill your JS with globals.

Comment: This is all valid, but related to the bug at hand.

Comment: @Matthew — The first two paragraphs of my answer explain why it **is** related.

Comment: @Quentin - Changing the layout of the HTML would have never solved the problem.  Browsers handle invalid layout, they dont handle unknown JavaScript function calls.

Comment: @Mathew — Some browsers handle the particular case of forms as parents of table rows by moving the form (but not its contents) outside of the table. That **will** break it. There might be *additional* problems, but this is a real one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint.. how do you spell "isNAN"?

This code is easily debugged by putting alert statements after each line of code.  If you use simple debugging like this, you will find that you have some invalid syntax.  I leave it to you to find the bug!

Comment: It's easier to debug by having a console open than by putting an alert after every statement, but +1 anyway. I'd do +0.5 if I could for encouraging alerts :p

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I really should have taken a look at this in a debug console before posting.  Not sure how I missed that NaN issue though.  Either way, thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `isNAN` with `isNaN` and it should work.